# Android, How do I exceed the per application memory limit?

Tags: android, memory-management

My android application is very memory intensive. In the manifest I have android:largeHeap="true". ActivityManager.getLargeMemoryClass() returns approximately half a gigabyte. My application regularly exceeds this amount - this is necessary, I assure you. When it does so, it does not crash immediately, but becomes prone to suddenly stopping and appearing to reload all the application icons on the home screen.

I have a few questions here:

1. Is it correct to assume that when my application exits with no message like "application has stopped working" and reloads the homescreen, that this is a memory error? If so, what exactly is happening?
2. Would exceeding the allocated memory limit make my application slow?
3. How can I reliably and safely exceed the application's memory limit?

Comment: If you could change the limit, then the new limit would be the limit. Without knowing what your app is doing and how it is doing it, Android is still a mobile device with memory and battery limitations. Logcat should provide some info if your app quits without the usual ANR. Otherwise add some internal state logging to know where things are failing.

Comment: "ActivityManager.getLargeMemoryClass() returns approximately half a gigabyte" -- on your test device, perhaps. You should not assume that it is nearly that large. "My application regularly exceeds this amount - this is necessary, I assure you" -- then perhaps you should be asking separate Stack Overflow questions, explaining why you are consuming this much heap space and seeking alternative approaches that use less. 
"Would exceeding the allocated memory limit make my application slow?" -- yes, in that the garbage collector will try desperately to prevent you from running out of memory.